# Dumping memory layout with clang

Tags: c++, memory, clang++, static-code-analysis

Hi search for a way to dump the memory layout of a class/structure/datatype with clang.
I have a simple application based on [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) tutorial.

I also added this function

```
 bool VisitFieldDecl(FieldDecl *F)
{
  F->dump();
  std::cerr << F->getQualifiedNameAsString()  << " " << F->getBitWidthValue(*Context) << " " << std::endl;
  F->dump() ;
  std::cerr << "-----------------------------------------" << std::endl;
  return true;
}
```

Unfortunately getBitWidthValue also returns zero for my types.

I need the complete memory-layout recursively for each class and all nested types. Including sizes/offsets.

Maybe the AST is the wrong place, and i need a other hook to start?

Comment: Why do you need it? The standard doesn't define memory layout, so you could potentially open a whole new set of problems by going that path. on the other hand sometimes you have no way out.

Comment: We have two libraries called [typelib](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/typelib) and [orogen](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/orogen) that provides ruby bindings and (de-)serialization information. This uses currently gcc-xml. Since we are unhappy with that we are looking for a replacement. What do you mean with "The standard dosn't define..."

Comment: What it means is that if you have two adjacent data structures (in an array) the amount of padding the compiler may choose is arbitrary. Whenever I had to write serializers I made sure I don't cast but instead copy the values from the serial stream and vice versa.

Comment: It is not arbitrary, there are under laying rules. So far we are using a Principe like in the above mentions libs.

Comment: try `struct foobar { double x; }; struct foobar arr1[10]; double arr2[10];` I've observed that IAR uses a different alignment on arr1 to arr2. on gcc the alignment was the same. It has to stay consistent within the compiler. Since you mention ruby I doubt that you can create a hand crafted serialization pattern for every class though. and you have to use some kinf of compiler aid/information anyway.

Comment: Theoretical you are right, but we are using without any problems the setup with the gccxml since 5 years. Even the exchange of data structures between libs normally working fine even not defined in general.

Comment: That was a hint that you should be careful. the byte layout should  be specified in the ABI you are using. if you can limit the number of compilers and make sure the abi is compatible it is possible. Also take 64bit vs. 32bit ABI incomatibilities into your considerations. consider that the person who implemented the serializer with gccxml possibly ran into the problems and limitations. So there might be places in the code that workaround ABI incompatibilities to work across other compilers. make sure you test your (de)serialization across the compilers (and different ABI) you support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the "AST Record Layout" of a given `const clang::CXXRecordDecl* decl` in llvm/clang-3.4:

```
const clang::ASTRecordLayout &typeLayout(decl->getASTContext().getASTRecordLayout(decl));
std::cout << "record '" << decl->getQualifiedNameAsString() << "' with " <<  typeLayout.getSize().getQuantity() << "bytes\n";

for(clang::RecordDecl::field_iterator fit = decl->field_begin(); fit != decl->field_end(); fit++) {
    const clang::QualType qualType = fit->getType().getLocalUnqualifiedType().getCanonicalType();
    size_t fieldOffset = typeLayout.getFieldOffset(fit->getFieldIndex());
    std::cout << "member '" << qualType.getAsString() << "' with " << fieldOffset/8 << " bytes offset\n";
}
```

no warranties: Code copied together, not tested as typed here -- but should work... (tm)

Example:

```
struct EXAMPLE
{
    char a;
    int b;
    long c;
    long long d;
    float e;
    double f;
};
```

Output:

```
record 'EXAMPLE' with 40 bytes
member 'char' with 0 bytes offset
member 'int' with 4 bytes offset
member 'long' with 8 bytes offset
member 'long long' with 16 bytes offset
member 'float' with 24 bytes offset
member 'double' with 32 bytes offset
```

for more see:
https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html
https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTRecordLayout.html

Comment: fieldOffset in code above should be divided by 8 as getFieldOffset() return value is in bits, not bytes.